# Intel compiler - Can't install packages in R that require eventloop.h

Tags: r, compiler-errors, icc, intel-mkl

Seems like I can't install any packages in R that require <s>any files to be compiled.</s>  eventloop.h

I did a custom install of R with intel compilers and linked to the intel MKL BLAS library.

Here is the specific error I am getting:

```
> install.packages("setwidth")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Selection: 77
trying URL 'http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/CRAN/src/contrib/setwidth_1.0-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3789 bytes
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 3789 bytes

* installing *source* package ‘setwidth’ ...
** package ‘setwidth’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
icc -std=c99 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O3 -ipo -xavx -openmp  -c setwidth.c -o setwidth.o
In file included from setwidth.c(4):
/usr/local/lib/R/include/R_ext/eventloop.h(73): error: identifier "fd_set" is undefined
  extern InputHandler *getSelectedHandler(InputHandler *handlers, fd_set *mask);
                                                                  ^
... more of the same ...

                  ^

compilation aborted for setwidth.c (code 2)
make: *** [setwidth.o] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘setwidth’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/setwidth’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpXuQs4W/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("setwidth") :
  installation of package ‘setwidth’ had non-zero exit status
```

Let me know any additional info you might need to help me troubleshoot this.

EDIT:

I tried adding

```
R_XTRA_CFLAGS = -I /src/include -I /src/include/sys
```

to my ~/.R/Makevars file because `fd_set` is defined in `/sys/select.h` No luck with that anyone have any ideas???

EDIT:

So this problem does not occur with every package, only packages that require certain R headers. So far I have only had problems with packages written by a certain author (all the packages required for integration of R with VIM, http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/vim-r-plugin.html) Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

seems to be a compiler issue:

```
gcc -I /usr/include/ -I /usr/local/lib/R/include/ -c setwidth.c
```

works however

```
icc -std=c99 -I /usr/include -I /usr/local/lib/R/include  -O3 -ipo -xavx -openmp -c setwidth.c
```

does not

Comment: Where did you install the R headers?

Comment: where would that be specified, I don't think I specified that

Comment: Depends on your OS. Did you follow the instructions in [R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html), specifically 6.3 and appendix A?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I am on an ubuntu OS. I still can't figure out what the problem was, I've review the R installation and Administration documents, any more tips/ideas?

Comment: Hmm the problem seems to only impact this one package (so far) I was able to install ggplots2. I've contacted the author, but idk if that will go anywhere

Comment: Author responded and pointed out that the error is occurring in `eventloop.h` an R header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this was an appropriate solution but when I peeked inside of `/usr/local/lib/R/include/R_ext/eventloop.h` I saw the following in the include statements:

```
#ifndef R_EXT_EVENTLOOP_H
#define R_EXT_EVENTLOOP_H

#ifndef NO_C_HEADERS
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H
# include <sys/select.h>    /* for fd_set according to recent POSIX */
#endif
/* NOTE: Needed at least on FreeBSD so that fd_set is defined. */
# include <sys/types.h>
#endif
```

As you can see sys/select.h is only included conditional on some variable HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H. I took out this condition statement:

```
#ifndef R_EXT_EVENTLOOP_H
#define R_EXT_EVENTLOOP_H

#ifndef NO_C_HEADERS
# include <sys/select.h>    /* for fd_set according to recent POSIX */
/* NOTE: Needed at least on FreeBSD so that fd_set is defined. */
# include <sys/types.h>
#endif
```

And the package compiled (and installed) successfully. If anyone has any insight into why this particular variable `HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H` was not properly defined please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Let's back up a little:

1. Ubuntu is extremely widely used with R.
2. You could just install the [prebuilt current binary from CRAN](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu)
3. You could then add the MKL as the BLAS are interchangeble due to their standard interface. (This is frequently misunderstood; see my [gcbd vignette](http://cran.rstudio.com//web/packages/gcbd/vignettes/gcbd.pdf) for some details)
4. By staying with a more common setup, you can *easily* compile packages, or get prebuilt ones.
5. And you can then study your Intel icc setup a little more closely.

Currently it is broken, and you get to keep both pieces.

*Edit:* To make it more plain, on a standard Ubuntu system with the Ubuntu binary package off CRAN:

```
edd@max:~$ install.r setwdith
Warning message:
package ‘setwdith’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2) 
edd@max:~$ install.r setwidth
trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/setwidth_1.0-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3789 bytes
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 3789 bytes

* installing *source* package ‘setwidth’ ...
** package ‘setwidth’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
ccache gcc-4.8 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -g0 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99  -c setwidth.c -o setwidth.o
ccache gcc-4.8 -shared -o setwidth.so setwidth.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/setwidth/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (setwidth)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
edd@max:~$
```

Here `install.r` is a script from my [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) package; the compiler setting is my default of wrapping via the (awesome) [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) tool.

Comment: thanks for the ideas. I am quite familiar with how to set up R. I was trying to squeeze a little more performance out of my build thought by using intel MKL and the intel compilers. I'm not quite clear on what you were suggesting: you think i should just forget about the intel compilers?

Comment: No. I was suggestion three things. 1) Debug by simplifying (but you found the guilty party, here icc, anyway. 2) Use BLAS by just exchanging them, see my vignette for details -- no need to *recompile R* for that. 3) Intel icc is good, though recent gcc/g++ is said to have closed the gap; the R Inst + Admin manual has details on using icc as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The problem ended up revolving around a particular environment variable (see my answer), and it didn't require so much debugging :)